# How to drop multiple columns in Deedle

Tags: c#, deedle

I am trying to drop multiple columns from a Deedle Frame, however it seems that its C# API supports dropping only one column at a time:

```
df.DropColumn("a");
```

Something similar to this F# example will also work for me, but I have no Idea how to translate it to C#:

```
let df2 = df.Columns.[["a", "b", "c"]]
```

This should select only the specified columns into a new DF.

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame subsetting in C# seems to work by passing a string array as a Columns array index:

```
var df2 = df.Columns[new string[] {"a","b","c"}];
```

Comment: I think you should be able to make this a bit shorter using just `new[] { "a", "b" }`